# What causes this reflection/refractions on the water surface and how can I get rid of it?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials

I am working on a procedural water material with volumetrics, and having some problems,these reflections/refrections appearing -like doubling the check patter. I don't know why they occur , whether it is natural to have in such scene.
How can I avoid them?
thanks

[image]

Material output has a glass shader with volume node and displacement node applied.

Comment: Hello ideorium, have you figured out why the double reflections in your scene? I'm having the same issue probably in my scene, looking for a solution..

Comment: @Booth no I haven't really, didn't received any answer here either. I think it was causing because of the shader node set-up which i got it from chocofur, so i changed the glass/water shader to another one, I wish I found it out though

Comment: In my node set-up I use a Layer Weight node with a blend value and I found out this much: if I take out the layer weight node the unwanted reflection isn't there.. unfortunately however I need the layer weight node to get the glass I want..

Comment: @Booth i'll try it on mine too then, see how it works, but glass without glossiness doesn't look realistic , i believe you are using layer weight for reflection, right?

Comment: I'm using layer weight to make the glass more transparent head-on and more reflective when seen from an angle. Layer weight blends between a transparent and a glass shader in my case. When I change the blend setting, the unwanted reflection changes too.